# Cannot start clickhouse-jdbc in Kafka Connect docker container

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, clickhouse

Main purpose is transfer data from Kafka topic into Clickhouse table. I guess one can think why not to use Clickhouse Kafka Engine? Well, there is [known problem - duplicated messages](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/6661). I tried up to [latest version of Clickhouse server](https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server) but it's all the same.

So, I decided to use Kafka Connect JdbcSinkConnector but got an error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:clickhouse://localhost:8123/default   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)   at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.getConnection(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:211)
>   at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.newConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:88)
>   at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider.getConnection(CachedConnectionProvider.java:62)
>   at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:56)
>   at
>   io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74) 
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:538)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
>   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Clickhouse JDBC driver need to be install. I found [the official JDBC driver](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc/releases/tag/release_0.2.4) and downloaded clickhouse-jdbc-0.2.4.jar from 'releases' tab into container.

Also installed jdk:

```
apt-get update && apt-get update
apt-get install default-jdk
```

By the way Kafka Connect docker container is built from this image:

```
confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.2.1
```

I tried to run the jar-file in several ways (there is no `Main-Class` in `MANIFEST.MF`):

```
java -jar clickhouse-jdbc-0.2.4.jar
```

This returned the error:

> no main manifest attribute, in clickhouse-jdbc-0.2.4.jar

Then I found out that if there is no `Main-Class` in `MANIFEST.MF` the `-jar` won't work. And I tried command:

```
java -cp clickhouse-jdbc-0.2.4.jar ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver
```

And fail again with error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver

What is the correct way to install [clickhouse-jdbc](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc)?

Comment: and you need clickhouse-jdbc-0.2.4-shaded.jar (5MB)

Not the clickhouse-jdbc-0.2.4.jar (202kb) -- it's only CH-jdbc code without 3party libs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Drivers don't have main classes. You cannot run them directly.
2. The Docker image already has a valid JDK, and installing another won't solve the error.
3. The ClickHouse Kafka Ingestor *probably* has "at-least-once" semantics, so duplicates cannot be avoided, anyway. The JDBC Source Connector can have the same issue.
4. You would put the Driver JAR under `/usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc` - https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#no-suitable-driver-found